# How can I set my own custom keys and values from JSON deserialized output?

Tags: apex

How do I copy JSON deserialized output into the **keys** AND **values** positions in a Map variable? I see plenty of examples discuss setting **values** but NOT the keys themselves. Would it be something like the following if my JSON output was the below?

```
Map<String, Object> json_output = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
    List<Object> parsed_json = (List<Object>)json_output.get('value');
    Map<String, Object> return_atts = new Map<String, Object>();
    for (Object LvL1attributes : parsed_json){
        return_atts.put(((Map<String, Object>)l1atts).get('displayName'), ((Map<String, Object>)l1atts).get('id'))
    }
```

JSON output:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "name": "Air Folder",
            "webUrl": "https://example.com/xxxxx/",
            "createdBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "Mark@example.com",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "displayName": "Mark"
                }
            },
            "lastModifiedBy": {
                "user": {
                    "email": "Mark@example.com",
                    "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                    "displayName": "Mark"
                }
            },
....}]
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when you paste in code it's a good idea to format in a way to where you can get rid of the horizontal scroll bar to make it easier for us to read (you can view my example in my answer for some tips on how to do this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only issue I see in your code is that I don't see "displayName" as a value in your JSON so you may get a "null" as your key which would not be good. I think you meant to do something more like this:

```
for (Object LvL1attributes : parsed_json){
    Map<String, Object> obj = (Map<String, Object>) LvL1attributes;
    return_atts.put('displayName', obj.get('id'));
}
```

But than again I also don't see Id as an attribute of JSON so it could just be left out. If you really do have an attribute called "displayName" and an attribute called "Id" then your code is probably fine. Maybe consider adding in a null check on the attributes before attempting to use them:

```
Map<String, String> return_atts = new Map<String, String>();

for (Object LvL1attributes : parsed_json) {
    Map<String, Object> obj = (Map<String, Object>) LvL1attributes;
    String displayName = (String) obj.get('displayName');
    String Id = (String) obj.get(Id);

    if (displayName != null && Id != null) {
        return_atts.put(displayName, Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I do. What' I'm trying to do is instead of typing something like 'displayName', do something like this: `return_atts.put('obj.get('displayName'), obj.get('id'))` where you don't specify the actual key name, but substitute it with the JSON value 'displayName' calls. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, I updated my answer to show what you might want that to look like.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point about the NULL parameters. I didn't think of that. I know the displayName variables won't return NULL values, but the ID field might.

Comment: I'd say that the general answer to your question is "yes you're doing it mostly right".  If that satisfies your needs please accept the answer. If you have a specific problem with the code, feel free to open another question.

Comment: gNerb, something to comment on your answer, the displayName and Id strings actually have to be of Type<Object> to work since you're using Strings to perform the value lookups. Just an FYI.

Comment: Sorry, I disagree but you're right in that my code is not 100% correct. I'll update my code. But they should still be type string. Even if you're converting this back into JSON having them as type string is still a good idea as it allows the destination service to be tightly typed as opposed to loosely typed.